# How do you loop for n-columns and use conditionals?

Tags: r, loops, stringr, xtable

I'm trying to make a loop for a table that will be generated in 'xtable'.

This is what I did "manually" together is here:

**What I want to get**

```
library(dplyr)
X1 = c(4.70e1, 4.72e1, 4.76e1, 2.73e20)
X2 = c(4.67e1, 4.69e1, 4.77e1, 2.05e20)
col.nam = c("AIC(n)", "HQ(n)", "SC(n)", "FPE(n)")
tab.out = data.frame(col.nam, X1, X2)

n.tab = tab.out %>%
  mutate(test1 = if_else(tab.out$X1 < tab.out$X2,
                         paste0(X1,"$^{*}$"),
                         paste0(X1)),
         test2 = if_else(tab.out$X2 < tab.out$X1,
                         paste0(X2,"\\textsuperscript{*}"),
                         paste0(X2)))%>%
  select(col.nam, test1, test2)

#  col.nam      test1                        test2
#1  AIC(n)         47     46.7\\textsuperscript{*}
#2   HQ(n)       47.2     46.9\\textsuperscript{*}
#3   SC(n) 47.6$^{*}$                         47.7
#4  FPE(n)   2.73e+20 2.05e+20\\textsuperscript{*}
```

I want to make a loop for n-columns using conditionals as seen below in the code (**My current ugly and error-prone fix**):

**Lo que obtuve ?**

```
tab.out = data.frame(X1, X2)
tab.out$max<-apply(tab.out, 1, max)
for(i in names(tab.out)){
  tab.out[[paste(i, 'test', sep="_")]] <- if_else(tab.out[[i]] < tab.out$max,
                                               paste0(i, "\\textsuperscript{*}"),
                                               paste0(i))
}

#        X1       X2      max                X1_test                X2_test max_test
#1 4.70e+01 4.67e+01 4.70e+01                     X1 X2\\textsuperscript{*}      max
#2 4.72e+01 4.69e+01 4.72e+01                     X1 X2\\textsuperscript{*}      max
#3 4.76e+01 4.77e+01 4.77e+01 X1\\textsuperscript{*}                     X2      max
#4 2.73e+20 2.05e+20 2.73e+20                     X1 X2\\textsuperscript{*}      max
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it for n-columns and add the code output in latex.

```
X1 = c(4.70e1, 4.72e1, 4.76e1, 1.565)
X2 = c(4.67e1, 4.69e1, 4.77e1, 2.05e20)
X3 = c(1.67e1, 8.69e1, 2.77e1, 8.05e20)
tab.out = data.frame(X1, X2, X3)
tab.out$min<-apply(tab.out, 1, min)
for(i in names(tab.out)){
  tab.out[[paste(i, 'test', sep="")]] = if_else(tab.out[[i]] == tab.out$min,
                                                  paste0(tab.out[[i]], "\\textsuperscript{*}"),
                                                  paste0(tab.out[[i]]))
}

row.nam = c("AIC(n)", "HQ(n)", "SC(n)", "FPE(n)")
tab.out = data.frame(row.nam, tab.out)
tab.out = tab.out %>%
  select(row.nam, X1test, X2test, X3test)

#  row.nam                    X1test                   X2test                   X3test
#1  AIC(n)                        47                     46.7 16.7\\textsuperscript{*}
#2   HQ(n)                      47.2 46.9\\textsuperscript{*}                     86.9
#3   SC(n)                      47.6                     47.7 27.7\\textsuperscript{*}
#4  FPE(n) 1.565\\textsuperscript{*}                 2.05e+20                 8.05e+20
```

Output in latex:

```
colnames(tab.out) = c("Parameters", "Lag 1", "Lag 2", "Lag 3") #$m^r_t$
print(xtable::xtable(tab.out, 
                     header = F, 
                     caption = "asdasdasdasd",
                     label="table:tb1",
                     align="llccc"),
      hline.after = c(-1,0), 
      include.rownames=FALSE, 
      include.colnames = TRUE,
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(nrow(tab.out)),
                        command = paste("\\hline \n",
                                        "\\multicolumn{4}{l}{\\footnotesize{$^{*}$Indicates the selected order of lag}} \\\\",
                                        "\\multicolumn{4}{l}{\\footnotesize{\\textit{Elaboration: The authors}}}",
                                        sep = "")), comment=FALSE,
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done directly with vectorized operations without using any "apply" functions or loop.

```
cols <- names(tab.out)[-1]
tab.out$max <- pmax(tab.out$X1, tab.out$X2)
tab.out[paste0(cols, "_test")] <- as.list(cols)
inds <- tab.out$X1 > tab.out$X2
tab.out$X1_test[!inds] <- paste0(tab.out$X1_test[!inds], "\\textsuperscript{*}")
tab.out$X2_test[inds] <- paste0(tab.out$X2_test[inds], "\\textsuperscript{*}")
tab.out

#  col.nam       X1       X2      max                X1_test                X2_test
#1  AIC(n) 4.70e+01 4.67e+01 4.70e+01                     X1 X2\\textsuperscript{*}
#2   HQ(n) 4.72e+01 4.69e+01 4.72e+01                     X1 X2\\textsuperscript{*}
#3   SC(n) 4.76e+01 4.77e+01 4.77e+01 X1\\textsuperscript{*}                     X2
#4  FPE(n) 2.73e+20 2.05e+20 2.73e+20                     X1 X2\\textsuperscript{*}
```

---

To do this for multiple columns, we can create a vector of pairs either manually or using a common string pattern between the column names (we can use `grep` here) or based on position.

```
X1_pairs <- c('X1')
X2_pairs <- c('X2')
```

We can create a function using the above commands to apply it to two columns at a time.

```
apply_fun <- function(x, y) {
   tab.out[paste0("max", x)] <- pmax(tab.out[[x]], tab.out[[y]])
   tab.out[paste0(c(x, y), "_test")] <- list(x, y)
   inds <- tab.out[[x]] > tab.out[[y]]
   tab.out[!inds, paste0(x, "_test")] <- paste0(tab.out[[x]][!inds], "\\textsuperscript{*}")
   tab.out[inds, paste0(y, "_test")] <- paste0(tab.out[[y]][inds], "\\textsuperscript{*}")
   tab.out
}
```

And use a `for` loop to apply it for every pair.

```
for (i in seq_along(X1_pairs)) {
    tab.out <- apply_fun(X1_pairs[i], X2_pairs[i])
}
```

Comment: I ran the code but it didn't work, plus I would like to try pasting the values of each vector (`Xi$^{*}$`) for n-columns. Thank you.

Comment: @cristian1512 Do you have multiple such pairs of columns that you are trying to compare? What are their names? Can you show a bigger example with expected output?

Comment: What I want is to speed up the process because in the example I proposed there are only vectors `X1` and `X2`. But if I have 50 vectors, how can I speed up the process without having to write *(in your case)* `tab.out$X1_test[!inds] <- paste0(tab.out$X1_test[!inds], "\textsuperscript{*}")` to `tab.out$X50_test[!inds] <- paste0(tab.out$X1_test[!inds], "\textsuperscript{*}")` ?  (That's why I was trying to make a loop.)

Comment: @cristian1512 Ok...I have updated the answer , please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much I managed to do what I wanted, with your code I realized the mistake I was making.